# Breaking changes have broken Rx samples

Tags: observablecollection, system.reactive

There are a few samples from the 101 Rx Samples from Rx Wiki that don't actually work anymore. I think it's because the latest Rx version I have (1.0.10621.2) but I'd like to confirm and see how I can get them to work.

For example, the following sample code doesn't work:

```
class ObserveEvent_Generic
{
    public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs { }
    public static event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> GenericEvent;

    static void Main()
    {
        // To consume GenericEvent as an IObservable:
        IObservable<IEvent<SomeEventArgs>> eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent<SomeEventArgs>(
            ev => GenericEvent += ev,
            ev => GenericEvent -= ev);
    }
}
```

The IEvent is missing and "ev => GenericEvent += ev" is causing a "Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Action<xxx>` to `System.EventHandler<xxx>` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options in this case. The first is to provide a delegate that matches the standard EventHandler pattern (the resulting Observable is of type `IObservable<SomeEventArgs>`). Notice the lamda I provided accepts "`o`" (the "sender"), but this param is not used:

```
IObservable<SomeEventArgs> eventAsObservable = 
Observable.FromEvent<SomeEventArgs>
(
    ev => GenericEvent += (o,e) => ev(e),
    ev => GenericEvent -= (o,e) => ev(e)
);
```

Especially in your situation (static event... yikes!), I would be reticent to trust that the unsubscribe would truly cleanup properly and you might end up with a nasty memory leak depending on usage. As an alternative, you can specify the delegate type. Notice here the extra generic parameter to `FromEvent`

```
IObservable<SomeEventArgs> eventAsObservable = 
Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>, SomeEventArgs>
(
    ev => GenericEvent += ev,
    ev => GenericEvent -= ev
);
```

One more alternative that moves the handling of the source/sender object to the Observer (making the observable of type `IObservable<EventPattern<SomeEventArgs>>`) is to use the `FromEventPattern` method. I've had a little trouble with this method in some builds, so your mileage may vary, but here is that alternative:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<SomeEventArgs>> eventAsObservable = 
Observable.FromEventPattern<SomeEventArgs>
(
    ev => GenericEvent += ev,
    ev => GenericEvent -= ev
);
```

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The `FromEvent` extension method has been renamed to `FromEventPattern` so do this and the 101 samples should work.

The confusing thing is that a new `FromEvent` overload was created for non-standard events. They should have called it `FromEventAction` but they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of samples from [Programming Reactive Extensions and LINQ by Jesse Liberty and Paul Betts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430237473)  book is broken :( :( It's so sad...